# Is it possible to tell if a user is using Apple's voice control speech recognition software on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, speech-recognition

I checked before asking but couldn't find any answers. I'm working on accessibility fixes on a website and one autocomplete component doesn't work with Apple's Voice Control software (because VC doesn't support `role="combobox"`).

Is there a way I can check to see if a user is using Voice Control, so that I can provide them with a different component?

Through user research we can see that the majority of users like the autocomplete component, so we don't just want to bin it because Voice Control doesn't work on it. It works well with other speech recognition software like Dragon.

Comment: What problems are you having with Voice Control? I'm no VC expert but recent experience in work is that it is fine with comboboxes, although the correct commands aren't always intuitive. (I wish there was better documentation on it!)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think you can tell programmatically if VC is being used, but even if you can, you really shouldn't because it's a slippery slope in terms of privacy to know what assistive technologies (if any) your users are using.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks for the reply. Yeah I agree about the privacy aspect. It's an input with the label 'name' and then it autocompletes a list of locations depending on what you type. Using VC I can't access the input by saying 'click name', even the 'show numbers' command doesn't show a number next to the label or input. The only way I can access it is by using 'show grid' and clicking on the input that way.

Comment: @RobinZigmond you get the same issue if you try VC here https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/combobox/grid-combo.html#ex1

Comment: hmm it seems you're right - it seems a lot of these commands are temperamental at best! But the same is often true with a vanilla HTML select, so I wouldn't worry too much. (I also can't seem to get them to work with the [Material UI version](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/) - even though I'm sure I could just the other day!) On the page you link to, I'm still able to eventually select the combobox with "next field" said enough times. I suspect the issues are with VC rather than your component but I accept that it's frustrating.

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you, very related: [Detecting Screen Readers – No](https://www.webaxe.org/detecting-screen-readers-no/)

Comment: Maybe there would be a way to apply progressive enhancement? Especially with CSS we have used browser-hacks for a long time, before @support queries were there. Maybe something similar could be found in this case? So your question would be how you could make your component work with Apple’s VC, while still providing a better interface to other VC.